# Decoding CSLA.NET communications in Fiddler

Tags: c#, wcf, fiddler, csla

I'd like to take a WCF SOAP request/response I captured in Fiddler and be able decode into a human readable format.  The traffic I'm capturing using Fiddler is coming from a Silverlight application that uses WCF/CSLA.NET.  Are there any inspectors out there that would do this (I couldn't find any in my research)?  If not, could anyone point me to some resources that describe how the requests/responses should be processed so I could build an inspector to do so?

Comment: I'm not sure what `csla.net` is, but have you tried this? http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/wcfbinaryinspector

Comment: Thanks.  Yeah, I've actually used that on previous projects, but that only works for WCF's binary-encoded XML format.  CSLA.NET has its own custom serialization/compression routine, so unfortunately that won't work

Comment: CSLA .NET can use a number of different .NET serializers (BinaryFormatter, NetDataContractSerializer, MobileFormatter). In addition WCF and/or IIS and/or ASP.NET may add encoding or compression.

Your best bet is to create a custom WcfProxy subclass, which has methods where you can see the data.